# I can only get 2g..how do i get 4glte on my lg optimus L90D415

Tags: lg, lg-optimus-l90

I have metro pcs and got perfect service lost my phone so using my old lg optimus L90D415 but cant get more than 2 g no matter what i do

Comment: According to [these](http://www.phonemore.com/lg-optimus-l90-d415/specs/1517) specifications, your model appears not to support 4G.

Answer (score 0):

D415, being a rather old low-end phone by nature, has no 4G support by hardware design, as indicated by the specs [here](http://pdadb.net/index.php?m=device&id=6038&c=lg_d415_optimus_l90__l_series_iii_l90__lg_w7).

The device does support UMTS on Band 2/4/5, and MetroPCS uses Band 2/4, so theoretically you should see 3G. However, as carriers have shifted their priorities towards LTE, 3G coverage on those bands will degenerate, especially as Band 2/4 are also primary LTE bands for the same carrier.